# Application Distribution with VS2012+MKL

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, dll, intel-mkl

I am trying to distribute my VS2012/MKL code to a separate computer. When on that computer I get a vcomp.dll not found. I understand that by using vcomp.dll, the application is using the MS OpenMP instead of libiomp.

I am trying to get around this dependency on MS OpenMP and searching through forums I made the following changes:

- Added the \compiler\lib\intel64 directory to "VC++ Directories"->Reference Directories and Library Directories
- Added libiomp5md.lib to Linker->Additional Dependencies
- Added vcomp.lib to Linker->Ignore Specific Default Libraries
- Added the \compiler\lib\intel64 to my Linker->Additional Library Directories for good measure.

Each change still loads vcomp110.dll: gives an error when trying to run on test machine and the load output on the dev machine lists vcomp110.dll. Are there additional steps I am missing to force VS to use libiomp instead of vcomp?

I cannot provide reproduce-able code to attach.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

From  the intel documentation located here: http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/studio/composer/en-us/2011Update/compiler_c/optaps/common/optaps_par_compat_libs_using.htm

> Using Intel OpenMP* Libraries from Visual Studio*
>
> When using systems running a Windows OS, you can make certain changes
>   in the Visual C++ Visual Studio 2005 development environment to allow
>   you to use the Intel C++ Compiler and Visual C++ to create
>   applications that use the Intel OpenMP libraries.
>
> NOTE:
>
> Microsoft Visual C++ must have the symbol _OPENMP_NOFORCE_MANIFEST
>   defined or it will include the manifest for the vcomp90 dlls. While
>   this may not appear to cause a problem on the build system, it will
>   cause a problem when the application is moved to another system that
>   does not have this DLL installed.
>
> Set the project Property Pages to indicate the Intel OpenMP run-time
>   library location:
>
> ```
> Open the project's property pages in from the main menu: Project > Properties (or right click the Project name and select Properties) .
>
> Select Configuration Properties > Linker > General > Additional Library Directories
>
> Enter the path to the Intel compiler libraries. For example, for an IA-32 architecture system, enter:
>
> <Intel_compiler_installation_path>\IA32\LIB
> ```
>
> Make the Intel OpenMP dynamic run-time library accessible at run-time;
>   you must specify the corresponding path:
>
> ```
> Open the project's property pages in from the main menu: Project > Properties (or right click the Project name and select Properties).
>
> Select Configuration Properties > Debugging > Environment
>
> Enter the path to the Intel compiler libraries. For example, for an IA-32 architecture system, enter:
> ```
>
> PATH=%PATH%;\IA32\Bin
>
> Add the Intel OpenMP run-time library name to the linker options and
>   exclude the default Microsoft OpenMP run-time library:
>
> ```
> Open the project's property pages in from the main menu: Project > Properties (or right click the Project name and select Properties).
>
> Select Configuration Properties > Linker > Command Line > Additional Options
>
> Enter the OpenMP library name and the Visual C++ linker option, /nodefaultlib.
> ```

I'm guessing the thing you're missing is the need to have _OPENMP_NOFORCE_MANIFEST defined.

Comment: Great first answer, noob!   ;-)